# SQL Server 2014 CTP1 Setup failed

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2014

I have uninstalled Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and install VS professional 2013

after, i tried to Setup Sql Server 2014 but a message say 
*"Installation blocked due to detection of version of Visual Studio that install SQL Server 2012 client libraries.."*

then i have uninstalled all Microsoft programs figured in this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2771441)  without uninstalling visual studio 2013 .
and always i get the same problem

[image]

any solutions Please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. At this point in time, [you should be using CTP2, not CTP1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/evalcenter/dn205290).
2. You should be installing the CTP on a clean machine (preferably a VM), not a system with a bunch of pre-existing software - especially from previous versions of SQL Server / Visual Studio. CTP2 might get around this particular issue for you, but it's still best practice IMHO to run beta software in a clean environment.
3. [Please review the release notes, in full, before proceeding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169381%28v=sql.15%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Aaron, i'm downloading the CTP2 now